# Show Message Box if TextBox is Blank or Empty using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to check first if users don not enter either User ID or Password, if either text box is blank or empty then  I want to show message box, if they enter both user id and password then I want to execute some other codes.  The problem I am having with the code is that the message does not show at all but the good thing is that it does not execute the other code. So I would like to see the message box to show up if both text boxes are empty.  I am not sure why the message box is not showing up even though I have used this same code in other functions and it worked.  thanks
here is my button code for the ASPX

```
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" BorderStyle="Groove" Height="109px" Visible="false"
            Width="870px" BackColor="#FFFFE1">
            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="DIGITAL SIGNATURE" Font-Bold="True" 
                ForeColor="#FF3300"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <br />

            <asp:Label ID="lblUID" runat="server" Text="User ID:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtUID" runat="server" Height="22px" Width="145px"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp;&nbsp;
            &nbsp;&nbsp;

            <asp:Label ID="lblPass" runat="server" Text="Password:"></asp:Label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPass" runat="server" Height="23px" TextMode="Password" style="margin-top: 0px"></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" Width="183px"
                onclick="btnSubmit_Click" 
                OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');" 
                Font-Bold="False" Font-Size="Medium" Height="30px" 
                style="margin-right: 1px" />
            <br />
        </asp:Panel>
```

code behind:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (txtUID.Text.Length == 0 || txtPass.Text.Length == 0)
        {

            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Please type your User ID and Password correctly and click Submit button again.  Thanks", true);

        }

        else
        {

              //execute some code here
        }
     }
```

Comment: Did you try and see by setting a breakpoint inside the if statement to see if the script is actually running or not ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code in btnSubmit_Click method, when you call RegisterClientScriptBlock you missed `');` symbols at then end of your alert. So, your javascript is incorrect, and browser displays an error in developers tools. It should be like this:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (txtUID.Text.Length == 0 || txtPass.Text.Length == 0)
    {

        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(),
            "alertMessage", 
            "alert('Please type your User ID and Password correctly and click Submit button again.  Thanks');", true);
    }
    else
    {
          //execute some code here
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (txtUID.Text.Length == 0 || txtPass.Text.Length == 0)
    {

         Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Please type your User ID and Password correctly and click Submit button again.  Thanks');", true);

    }

    else
    {

        //execute some code here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to do this client-side. You could change your `OnClientClick` to:

```
return login();
```

and then build the `login` function:

```
function login() {
    if ($('#txtUID').val() === '' ||
        $('#txtPass').val() === '') {
        alert('Please type your User ID and Password correctly and click Submit button again.  Thanks');
        return false;
    }

    return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit?');
}
```

and so now you can get rid of the server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

I have created common .js file which contains all client side validation as

```
function checkMandatory(ele)
 {
     var text;
     text = ele.value;
     if(text.length == 0)
     {
         alert("Please enter value ...");
         ele.focus();
         return;
     }
 }
```

Call function in Page_Load event as 
txtName.Attributes.Add("onFocusout", "checkMandatory(this);");

Note: Dont forget to include .js file to your page inside HTML tags.